# How do I use Wikipedia to find a technical translation?

Tags: traduction

If I'm on the English page
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridge_(music)
how do I get to the French page:
https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pont_(musique)

Someone showed me to to change the URL in the English page to get to the French page but I forgot how to do it. Is there another way?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this site is about the French language. Your question is better suited for Google or the Wikipedia forums.

Comment: You can try on [webapps.se]. But your question is so easily answered that I doubt it would be well received.

Comment: Vous avez raison.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to switch the language of the page, you can use links on the bottom of the left sidebar. The section is called "Languages".